# Inject requests into RingCentral queue

Tags: ringcentral

Our company has a web app and is going to introduce online chat feature. Since we already use RingCentral service with their call queue. I am not sure whether it's possible to achieve the following actions:

1. When users want to chat with customer service personnel, our web app can submit a request to RingCentral queue
2. Available person from the queue is going to be brought into the chat dialog of our web app.

I did some research on developer site of RingCentral but cannot find a proper reference so please share links so I can start from there if it's feasible. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If your agents are using RingCentral Engage Digital, this can be implemented using by adding your chat as a new channel with the Channel SDK:

https://developers.ringcentral.com/engage/digital/guide/sdks/source-sdk